# Animation doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uilabel, swift-playground

my name is Lennart and I'm currently working on a Playground for the WWDC. But unfortunately I have a problem with animating a label. Because of some reason the label doesn't even react to the animation, even though all the other labels do and it always animates one specific way (moves from the upper right corner to the middle). Here's my code:

```
startinglbl.text = "Tell us who you are"
    startinglbl.numberOfLines = 2
    startinglbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    startinglbl.frame = CGRect(x: 62, y: 62 + 10, width: 250, height: 100)
    startinglbl.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 40)
    startinglbl.textColor = UIColor.white
    startinglbl.textAlignment = .center
    startinglbl.alpha = 0
```

that's where I added some values to it and that's my animation:

```
func startingAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.startinglbl.frame = CGRect(x: 62, y: 62, width: 250, height: 100)
        self.startinglbl.alpha = 1
    }) { (true) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
            self.fntextfield.frame = CGRect(x: 87, y: 250, width: 200, height: 30)
            self.fntextfield.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { (true) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
                self.lntextfield.frame = CGRect(x: 87, y: 300, width: 200, height: 30)
                self.lntextfield.alpha = 1
            }, completion: { (true) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
                    self.startingbtn.frame = CGRect(x: 137, y: 450, width: 100, height: 50)
                    self.startingbtn.alpha = 1
                })
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help guys
Thank you very much

Comment: According to your code, startinglbl should animate to top by 10 pixel only.

Comment: Your completion handler is specified incorrectly.  It should be `completion: { (complete) in ...` `complete` is a boolean variable that indicates whether the animations are complete.

Comment: First I'ma aware that it only moves up 10 pixels but it also changes it's alpha to 1. And second thank you for your reply about the completion handler but unfortunately it doesn't change the result. It still only moves from the upper right corner into the middle of the screen.

Comment: And no matter what I change in the animation it doesn't change it's result

Comment: You can use this one is good: https://github.com/overboming/ZCAnimatedLabel

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that if you are using autolayout. then frame based animation does not work. like this :

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.4;
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    [_eraserSliderContainer.layer addAnimation:transition
                              forKey:kCATransition];
```

Comment: I'm actually not even using Auto Layout